# bash command to convert html page to a text file

Tags: bash

Would you please help me how to convert an html page to a text file. the text file will remove any images and links from the webpage. I want to use only bash commands and not html to text converting tools. As an example, i want to convert the first page google search results for "computers".

Comment: You are likely not going to be able to do it with only "bash commands", you are probably going to need at least `sed` or `awk`. Not saying it's not possible to do with just plain bash builtins, but it certainly is not feasible.

Comment: If you're using `curl` to get that page, you can pipe it to `| lynx -stdin -dump`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/608964/43233

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used [python-boilerpipe](https://github.com/misja/python-boilerpipe) and it works very well, so far...

Answer (score 57):

Easiest way is to use something like this which the dump (in short is the text version of viewable HTML).

Remote file:

```
lynx --dump www.google.com > file.txt
links -dump www.google.com
```

Local file:

```
lynx --dump ./1.html > file.txt
links -dump ./1.htm
```

With charset conversion to utf8 ([see](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/convert_from_html_to_formatted_plain_text.html)):

```
lynx -dump -display_charset UTF-8 ./1.htm
links -dump -codepage UTF-8 ./1.htm
```

Comment: Reading the comment page: `-dump:   dumps the formatted output of the default document`-- I take it "formatted" means, with all the html tags...

Comment: http://lynx.browser.org/lynx_help/body.html take a look for "assumed document charset" fields via DISPLAY_CHARSET_CHOICE and ASSUMED_DOC_CHARSET_CHOICE as i say it may be related to your version, Try the alternative links. Here are some more exampes http://www.microhowto.info/howto/convert_from_html_to_formatted_plain_text.html

Comment: If you want to use `w3m` to read from stdin in a pipe you need to add `-T text/html` to set the MIME type.

Answer (score 25):

You have [html2text.py](https://github.com/aaronsw/html2text) on command line.

Usage: `html2text.py [(filename|url) [encoding]]`

```
Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --ignore-links        don't include any formatting for links
  --ignore-images       don't include any formatting for images
  -g, --google-doc      convert an html-exported Google Document
  -d, --dash-unordered-list
                        use a dash rather than a star for unordered list items
  -b BODY_WIDTH, --body-width=BODY_WIDTH
                        number of characters per output line, 0 for no wrap
  -i LIST_INDENT, --google-list-indent=LIST_INDENT
                        number of pixels Google indents nested lists
  -s, --hide-strikethrough
                        hide strike-through text. only relevent when -g is
                        specified as well
```

Comment: For clarification, this answer was edited in 2014 to link to https://github.com/aaronsw/html2text python project , which points to a different program (`html2text.py`) than what I think the original author intended (Ubuntu/Debian [html2text](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/html2text.1.html), a c++ program). Anyways, too late to change, but I thought I'd point it out because of confusion.

Answer (score 23):

On OSX you can use the command line tool called textutil to batch convert html files to txt format:

```
textutil -convert txt *.html
```

Comment: How to apply this to all subdirectories?

Comment: It didn't work for me! The output is just the same XHTML that I had!

Comment: @MehdiAbbassi I suspect that because it's XHTML, textutil is unable to properly convert. It likely only supports standard HTML.

Answer (score 14):

in ubuntu/debian `html2text` is a good select. http://linux.die.net/man/1/html2text

Comment: Note, this is a different program than the other answer for `html2text.py` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422289/bash-command-to-convert-html-page-to-a-text-file/12422876#12422876

Comment: Of all the ones I've tried, this one in the Debian repos does the best job on my corpus.  Latest source github: https://github.com/grobian/html2text

Answer (score 10):

You could get [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) and globally install the module [@html-to/text-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@html-to/text-cli):

```
npm install -g @html-to/text-cli
```

Then use it like this:

```
html-to-text < stuff.html > stuff.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

Using sed

```
sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' foo.html
```

Comment: Thanks. this is really helpful. however, this did not work when the <....> pattern is more than one line.

Comment: It will also output contents of such elements as <script> which aren't needed.

Comment: How should I change this script to put a new line whenever it removes something?

Comment: sed -e 's/<[^>]*>/\n/g' foo.html > foo.txt

Answer (score 3):

I think links is the most common tool to do this. Check man links and search for plain text or similar. -dump is my guess, search for that too. The software comes with most distributions.

Answer (score 3):

The [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) tool can convert HTML to plain text (among several other markup formats) and I prefer how it formats text when compared to several of the other tools in answers here — it uses lots of whitespace, like a browser does, instead of packing everything together like `html2text` does. You might want to compare a few tools and then select one. To install it on Ubuntu or Debian:

```
sudo apt install pandoc
```

It has options to read and write from files, but I find it easiest to use in pipe mode, where you only have to specify the format to convert from and to:

```
curl URL | pandoc -f html -t plain > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

batch mode for local htm & html file, `lynx` required

```
#!/bin/sh
# h2t, convert all htm and html files of a directory to text 

for file in `ls *.htm`
do
new=`basename $file htm`
lynx -dump $file > ${new}txt 
done
#####
for file in `ls *.html`
do
new=`basename $file html`
lynx -dump $file > ${new}txt 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash script to recursively convert html page to text file. 
Applied to httpd-manual.
Makes grep -Rhi 'LoadModule ssl' /usr/share/httpd/manual_dump -A 10 work convenient.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Adapted from ewwink, recursive html to txt dump
# Made to kind of recursively (4 levels) dump the /usr/share/httpd manual to a dump httpd manual directory into a txt dump including dir
# put this script in /usr/share/httpd for it to work (after installing httpd-manual rpm)

for file in ./manual/*{,/*,/*/*,/*/*/*}.html
do
new=`basename $file .html`
mkdir -p ./manual_dump/${new}
lynx --dump $file > ./manual_dump/${new}.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

How I solved it:

```
# remove line breaks
html_content=$(echo "$html_content" | tr -d '\n')

# replace tabs
html_content=$(echo "$html_content" | tr '\t' ' ')

# enhance readability of table cells by adding a pipe
html_content=$(echo "$html_content" | sed -E 's#(<\/td>|<\/th>)# | \1#g')

# enhance readability of lists
html_content=$(echo "$html_content" | sed -E 's#(<li>|<li [^>]*>)#\n\1- #g')

# enhance readability of headlines
html_content=$(echo "$html_content" | sed -e 's/<h1>/<h1># /g' -e 's/<h2>/<h2>## /g' -e 's/<h3>/<h3>### /g')

# put comments, scripts and styles into separate lines
# enhance readability by adding line breaks after line-breaking elements
html_content=$(echo "$html_content" | sed -E -e "s#(<!--|<script|<styles)#\n\1#g" -e "s#(-->|</script>|</styles>|</tr>|</table>|</p>|</caption>|</div>|</h[0-9]>)#\1\n#g")

# remove comments, scripts and styles
html_content=$(echo "$html_content" | grep -v -e '^<!--' -e '^<script' -e '^<style')

# strip tags
html_content=$(echo "$html_content" | sed -E 's/<[^>]*>//g')

# reduce white spaces
html_content=$(echo "$html_content" | tr -s ' ')

# trim white space
html_content=$(echo "$html_content" | sed -e 's/^ //' -e 's/ $//')

# remove empty lines
html_content=$(echo "$html_content" | tr -s '\n')
```

Possible enhancements:

- add image `src` to output
- capture links like `[A linked phrase](https://example.com)`
- repeat table cell content by counting `colspan` and `rowspan`

Answer (score 0):

PHP way (using [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)):

```bash
php -r 'echo strip_tags(file_get_contents("./file.html"));' > file.txt
```

or:

```bash
cat file.html | php -r 'echo strip_tags(file_get_contents("php://stdin"));' > file.txt
```

Remember: this solution will just remove all HTML tags and will keep all "non-html" stuff (spaces, tabs, `CSS` and `JS` inline code...).