# Remove/replace html tags in bash

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I have a file with lines that contain:

```
<li><b> Some Text:</b> More Text </li>
```

I want to remove the html tags and replace the `</b>` tag with a dash so it becomes like this:

```
Some Text:- More Text
```

I'm trying to use sed however I can't find the proper regex combination.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/580412

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you strictly want to strip all HTML tags, but at the same time *only* replace the `</b>` tag with a `-`, you can chain two simple `sed` commands with a pipe:

```
cat your_file | sed 's|</b>|-|g' | sed 's|<[^>]*>||g' > stripped_file
```

This will pass all the file's contents to the first `sed` command that will handle replacing the `</b>` to a `-`. Then, the output of that will be piped to a `sed` that will replace all HTML tags with empty strings. The final output will be saved into the new file `stripped_file`.

Using a similar method as the other answer from @Steve, you could also use `sed`'s `-e` option to chain expressions into a single (non-piped command); by adding `-i`, you can also read-in and replace the contents of your original file without the need for `cat`, or a new file:

```
sed -i -e 's|</b>|-|g' -e 's|<[^>]*>||g' your_file
```

This will do the replacement just as the chained-command above, however this time it will directly replace the contents in the input file. To save to a new file instead, remove the `-i` and add `> stripped_file` to the end (or whatever file-name you choose).

Comment: This helped me fix some xml files with `variable="x"` type text. Used `s/' variable="'[^\"]*\"//` to match the tag name and everything between the next two double quotes. (ignore the funky mix of single and escaped double quotes)

Comment: Recommending `cat | sed | sed` and then mentioning in passing that in fact all you need is `sed` seems misdirected.  "You could also" just not recommend the flawed approach.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `GNU sed`:

```
sed -e 's/<\/b>/-/g' -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' file.txt
```

Example:

```
echo "<li><b> Some Text:</b> More Text </li>" | sed -e 's/<\/b>/-/g' -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

Result:

```
 Some Text:- More Text
```

Answer (score 0):

In BASH you can also use a `CLI browser` or `PHP` to parse and clean any HTML, they are probably much more effective than `sed` (in this context) but, of course, you have to install them first:

W3M:

```bash
echo '<li><b> Some Text:</b> More Text </li>' | w3m -dump -T text/html
```

Lynx:

```bash
echo '<li><b> Some Text:</b> More Text </li>' | lynx --dump
```

Links:

```bash
echo '<li><b> Some Text:</b> More Text </li>' | links -dump
```

([Credits here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12423133/2864348))

PHP:

```bash
echo '<li>My html</li>' | php -r 'echo strip_tags(file_get_contents("php://stdin"));'
```

Remember:

- The `CLI browsers` solution will literally render the HTML into text, removing any kind of code (inline JS and CSS as well) and also trying to format it at the best following HTML rules.
- The `PHP` solution, by using [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), will just remove all HTML tags and will keep all "non-html" stuff (spaces, tabs, inline CSS and JS code...) more or less like most `sed`/`regex` solutions would do.