# How to extract the source of a webpage without tags using bash?

Tags: bash, curl, tags, extract, wget

We can download the source of the page using `wget` or `curl` , but I want to extract the source of the page without tags.
I mean extract it as text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash command to covert html page to a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422289/bash-command-to-covert-html-page-to-a-text-file)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pipe to a simple sed command :

```
curl www.gnu.org | sed 's/<\/*[^>]*>//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Curl, Wget and Apache Tika Server (locally) you can parse HTML into simple text directly from the command line.

First, you have to download the tika-server jar from the Apache site:
https://tika.apache.org/download.html

Then, run it as a local server:

```
$ java -jar tika-server-1.12.jar
```

After that, you can start parsing text using the following url:

http://localhost:9998/tika

Now, to parse the HTML of webpage into simple text:

```
 $ wget -O test.html YOUR-HTML-URL && curl -H "Accept: text/plain" -T test.html http://localhost:9998/tika
```

That should return the webpage text without tags.

This way you're using wget to download and save your desired webpage to "test.html" and then you use curl to send a request to the tika server in order to extract the text. Notice that it's necessary to send the header "Accept: text/plain" because tika can return several formats, not just plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Ruby script that uses Nokogiri to parse the HTML:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
html = Nokogiri::HTML(open 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129357')

text  = html.at('body').inner_text
puts text
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6161807/157328)

It would probably be simple to do with Javascript or Python if you're more comfortable with that, or search for a html-to-text utility. I imagine it would be very difficult to do this purely in bash.

See also: [bash command to covert html page to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422289/bash-command-to-covert-html-page-to-a-text-file)

Comment: I said 'Using Bash' not ruby

Comment: good luck with using only bash :) – see my edit and the link to another post